Conservative magnetic field
Are there any physical situations where we can say that the magnetic field $B$ is conservative? I mean, we know form Maxwell's fourth equation that $$\nabla \times B=\mu_0 (J+\varepsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}),$$ thus $B$ is conservative (at least, locally) if $J=0$ (absence of "magnetic sources") and there is no time-dependent electric field, but does this correspond to a real, physical situation, or it is just a conjecture?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_scalar_potential

Because they are generated neither by a current, nor an electric field?

for a permanent magnet the H field is potential because Maxwell's equation is $\nabla \times H = J +\partial D/\partial t$ and $J=0$ and $D$ is independent of time, and therefore $\nabla \times H=0$. If the magnet is also homogeneous, $M=const$, therefore $\nabla \times M=0$ all inside the magnet excluding boundary effects, and thus $\nabla \times B=0$ because $B=\mu_0(H+M)$. Outside the magnet $M=0$ and $B=\mu_0H$.

Ok, $J=0$ because we assume there are no macroscopic currents inside the magnet (after the processo of magnetization), but why $D$ does not depend on time?

B field is conservative outside and inside the magnet, but it is not conservative on the magnet surface, because $\nabla \times \mathbf B = \mu_0 \mathbf j_m$, where $\mathbf j_m = \nabla\times\mathbf M$, and this is non-zero on the magnet surface.

D changes when "macroscopical" charge density fluctuates; a permanent magnet is electrically neutral, there are no macroscopically free charges can accumulate even when it is a metal so there are no free charge currents in it. There are microscopic currents of the electrons as they move around randomly within the atoms/molecules but macroscopically they average to zero. This can change to a macroscopic ohmic current when you bias externally a magnetic metal. There are also permanent magnet ceramic insulators, these are also excellent insulators in normal size E fields and no free charges.

In any simply connected region with no current (see note 1) or Maxwell's displacement current, $\vec{B}$ is conservative. Since it is also solenoidal, this entails that it satisfies Laplace's Equation.
$$\nabla^2 \vec{B}=0$$
Further each Cartesian component of $\vec{B}$ is a harmonic function, completely specified by its boundary values.
The "simply connected" requirement is important. A magnetic field is not conservative in a toroid if current flows through the "doughnut hole".
Note 1. There are several different models of magnetization, and this may be a source of confusion. The Gilbert model of magnetization employs non-physical magnetic monopoles. However, the model used by, for example Griffiths in Introduction to Electrodynamics, treats all magnets as essentially electromagnets. Magnetization, in this model results from microscopic currents, such as electron "spin", or orbital "rotation". These many microscopic currents acting in unison next to each other result in a net macroscopic surface current at the boundary of the magnet and at the boundaries of magnetic domains, and if a magnetic domain is not uniformly magnetized, a volume current within that magnetic domain. Thus, a region with non-uniform magnetization would not satisfy the "no current" condition in the thesis statement of this answer. This answer assumes Griffiths' model of magnetization.

In general, even if J=0 and dD/dt=0 you can only say that $\nabla \times H =0$.  To be able say that $\nabla \times B =0$  you must assume some kind of material homogeneity so that $B=\mu H$ where $\mu(x)=const$ independent of position. Even then it does not follow that on the boundary of the magnet $\nabla^2 B=0$ that is now true within and without the magnet because there are "boundary surface currents" $\nabla \times M$ that act as the source for B.

@hyportnex If you follow, for example Griffiths, all magnets are essentially electromagnets, and have boundary surface current densities K, and if non-uniformly magnetized also have interior volume current densities J. Thus the requirement that J=0 inside a magnet entails that the magnet is uniformly magnetized. The alternative Gilbert model uses non-physical magnetic monopoles.
